# Export Oracle data to csv format

Tags: oracle, csv

I am able to generate a csv file in SQL Developer using the "set sqlformat csv" and alternatively using /*csv*/ in my query and spool off the results to a file.  This works fine.

I now wanted to create a generic procedure to generate the csv from an Oracle package/procedure using a passed SQL query.  Is it possible to use "set sqlformat csv" in this case?  I know I can use the UTL_FILE utility to write the file but the missing part is the automatic CSV formatting.  Thank in advance for your insight.

Comment: No, that is a sqlplus command. See this https://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2020/02/13/generating-csv-files-from-pl-sql-the-very-easy-way/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To generate >CSV file and automate send an email using Oracle PLSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72183649/to-generate-csv-file-and-automate-send-an-email-using-oracle-plsql). Or [Oracle how to export query to a text/csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857744/oracle-how-to-export-query-to-a-text-csv-file)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  The APEX solution looks good but it is currently not in our environment.  Leaning towards the solutions discussed on Mike's blog.  Thanks again.